# Python: Setting encoding at one place to treat unicode and non-unicode strings

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

We have an application which uses various python components - TurboGears, SQLAlchemy, MySQL (database), integration with different third-party APIs.
Python version 2.7

Essentially data flows between various systems:

- Inflow : from APIs connecting to external systems, and from our own
  application UI. The data is a mix of plain strings (which may have
  non-ASCII characters) and Unicode strings.
- Outflow : Data stored in the database is rendered on the application
  UI.

In this workflow, naturally we have data being stored and referenced from various data structures viz. dictionary, lists etc. In order to make our application I18N compliant, we are in the process of tightening the screws in the code to ensure we are working and referencing Unicode (UTF8) strings at all places for string comparisons and data retrieval.

There are several questions:

1. Is there a common place where we can set the encoding, so that the
   python code always explicitly uses UTF8 encoding while treating it's
   string literals. Does something like sys.setdefaultencoding(utf-8)
   before loading the python code work?
2. If there is a common place, does all string literals in the code get transformed to Unicode. for e.g. **(myDict = {"key" : "abc"}** and **myDict = {u"key" : u"abc")** would be stored as 2 different k,v pairs}

Comment: _"1. Is there a common place where we can set the encoding, so that the python code always explicitly uses UTF8 encoding while treating it's string literals."_ - yeah, use Python 3; or if you can't try your luck with `from __future__ import` [`unicode_literals`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3112/)

Comment: `u'key' == 'key'` will always be True; thus you cannot store them as unique dict keys.

Comment: “so that the python code always explicitly uses UTF8 encoding while treating it's string literals” → That's the wrong approach. Always use Unicode strings for processing text. Can you include your python version in the question?

Comment: And string comparisons, that is part of what is called *collation*, which is an entirely separate problem.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid u'key' = 'key' returns true if the key is of ASCII characters. Consider the below example:                                           `code` >>> key = u"äöüü"
>>>
>>> test = {}
>>> test[key] = "abc"
>>> print test
{u'\xe4\xf6\xfc\xfc': 'abc'}
>>> key = "äöüü"
>>> test[key] = "xyz"
>>> print test
{'\xe4\xf6\xfc\xfc': 'xyz', u'\xe4\xf6\xfc\xfc': 'abc'}`code`